# new to gradle - why is there a dubug mode and release mode

Tags: java, android, gradle

I am new to this automated build stuff... why is there a 'debug' version for Android Gradle? I dont see the need for it because we can simply create a project, and run it in debug mode(step through the code...etc)... they why even have a debug mode version ?

also.. if i understand it correctly.. this whole gradle thing is so that... we can compile the project 2-3 times a day just to make sure it can compile.. because people are adding code to it... is that correct ?

I tried to look through some documentation but it was really difficult to understand.

Answer (score 0):

It's all about Agile Dev methodology

> The main reason of setting up multiple build types is that you can
>   create different build types for your app. For example, we have debug
>   builds for our developers, client builds that we share with our
>   clients at the end of a sprint, and release builds that we upload to
>   the Play Store for publicly released versions of an app.

Comment: but why cant they all be the same build?

Comment: because simply the way we build for release for clients os different from the way we build for testing and debugging as an example Logs we don't use them in release build

Comment: ok i understand... logs we dont need in production. anything else?